# Can not launch MySQL server in windows Server 2008 R2 EC2 machine

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008

I created a windows 2008 r2 server instance in amazon EC2. I downloaded MySQL installer but I'm facing a problem in the configuration. I have successfully installed and configured MySQL before but on Win7 and I did not do any special settings. I can not figure out what do I need to do in the current situation with 2008 server. The following are screen  shots for the problem.

[image]

The details:

[image]

Comment: which document u followed to configure? Share more info about steps u followed so it would be helpful to all to solve your issues..

Comment: I used Mysql installer http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ and left all the default settings.